# SQlite query to update column and replace a value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to update a column that contains a string like 12,43,433 I want to only replace 43 with another number say 54 so that the column value becomes 12,54,433.

How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing lists as strings is a *very* bad idea.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table, not a string.  The proper way to store lists is to use a junction table.

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  If so, you can do:

```
update t
    set col = trim(replace(',' || col || ',', ',43,', ',54,'), ',')
    where ',' || col || ',' like '%,43,%';
```

Notes:

- This works regardless of where the "43" appears in the string (including at the beginning and end).
- This maintains the format of the string with no commas at the beginning and end.
- This only attempts to update rows that have the particular elements in the list.

Use of such a query should really be a stopgap while you figure out how to fix the data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about db design , and for the answer, i know what should be done now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use REPLACE() function like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable a
SET a.StringColumn = REPLACE(a.StringColumn,',43,',',54,')
WHERE a.StringColumn like '%,43,%'
```

Comment: You missed comma after `54`.

Comment: @arvo Thumbs up, fixed.