# SQL update a column in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that contains a column value the column can have rows that have a single value or comma-separated values also.

For example,

```
VALUES
 23
 23,43,55
 43,23,55
 43,55,23
```

I need to replace all occurrences of 23 with 28 how can I do that.

Comment: Fix your data structure to use a junction table rather than lists of numbers stored as strings.

Comment: use Set values=28 where values=23

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field try this link

Comment: Isn't this the same post as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480041/sqlite-query-to-update-column ? you forgot your user?..

Comment: @sagi Probably the same homework question ...

Comment: @CL. its the exact same question half an hour later hh..

Answer (score 2):

Storing lists as strings is a very bad idea. SQL has a great data structure for storing lists. It is called a table, not a string. The proper way to store lists is to use a junction table.

Sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really bad design decisions. If so, you can do:

```
update t
    set col = trim(replace(',' || col || ',', ',23,', ',28,'), ',')
    where ',' || col || ',' like '%,23,%';
```

Notes:

This works regardless of where the "23" appears in the string (including at the beginning and end).
This maintains the format of the string with no commas at the beginning and end.
This only attempts to update rows that have the particular elements in the list.
Use of such a query should really be a stopgap while you figure out how to fix the data structure.